# Js format a date string

Tags: javascript, string, date

I get a JSON array from a rest call and one of its objects has got an attribute lastModified which is formatted such as:

```
'lastModified: "2018-03-19 13:02:53.0 UTC"'
```

I want to display it as a label on a radio button but not as "2018-03-19 13:02:53.0 UTC", what I want is to format it as "19 Mar 13:02".

How to format date and time in the way I want when showed?

Comment: I would just use moment.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the easiest way is to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.

```
moment("2018-03-19 13:02:53.0 UTC").format('DD MMM HH:mm');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ycu3p6tx/

Comment: Worked perfect! just wondering i got a warning "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format." is this something i will have to worry about?

Comment: You can provide the format when parsing, like `moment("2018-03-19 13:02:53.0 UTC", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss:S Z").format('DD MMM HH:mm');`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to create your Date object:

```js
var data = 'lastModified: "2018-03-19 13:02:53.0 UTC"';
var lastModified = data.split('"')[1].split(' ');
console.log(lastModified);

var datetime = new Date(lastModified[0] + 'T' + lastModified[1] + 'Z');

console.log(datetime);
```

Then use some library to format it as you need (for example moment.js)